# Git doesn't automatically resolve conflicts

Tags: git, clearcase, merge-conflict-resolution

This is a git-newbie question, however, I have almost 7 years of experience with clearcase, where what I am trying to achieve with git in this particular case is just plain simple. Anyway, I forked binutils on github and created a branch from the binutils-2_23_2 tag. I made some changes and it works. But I decided to ... and here's probably some difficulty with specifying what I decided to do (in term of clearcase/git vocabulary). In clearcase that would be:

1. I have a branch with changes taken from binutils-2_23_2, there a
   parent somewhere in the branch tree,
2. somewhere else in the branch
   tree I create another branch, this time going from the
   binutils-2_24-branchpoing tag,
3. then I 'merge' (cleartool merge -nc
   -g -to file file@@/version-specification) and clearcase finds the common ancestor, resolves all automatic conflicts and delegates all
   non-automatic conflicts resolution to e.g. three-way merge using
   kdiff3,

I am not quite sure how to do something similar in git. There seem to be two potential candidates - that is "merge" and "rebase", but which is right? My idea would be to checkout the new 2_24 development branch branch and then "merge" changes from the 2_23_2 development branch, but when I do that git shows plethora unresolved conflicts of which none are related to my changes. I would expect git to handle this by itsels, and present me with only those which relate to my work on the older development branch.

Comment: Git does automatically resolve conflicts, assuming those conflicts aren't changing the same lines of the file. Perhaps your line-endings are screwed up or something?

Comment: the files with associated conflicts weren't changes by me at all, let alone having EOLs being modified.

Comment: That's weird. Perhaps there are other changes on your branch that you aren't aware of? Try running `git merge-base branch1 branch2` to find the common ancestor of your branch and the branch you're merging. Then run `git diff <result of last command> HEAD` to review the changes made on your branch.

Answer (score 1):

The Git equivalent of the ClearCase merge would be [`git merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).

[`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) would be to replay one branch on top of the other.

---

The [OP Wojciech Migda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2003487/wojciech-migda) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123071/git-doesnt-automaticaly-resolve-conflicts/21123277?noredirect=1#comment31789914_21123277):

> for the moment I have reverted to generating and applying patches - with this (plus some manual patch edit) it worked

That can work if the common ancestor is too old between the two branches.

As [Ajedi32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1157054/ajedi32) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123071/git-doesnt-automaticaly-resolve-conflicts/21123277?noredirect=1#comment31788797_21123071):

> Try running `git merge-base branch1 branch2` to find the common ancestor of your branch and the branch you're merging.
>   Then run `git diff <result of last command> HEAD` to review the changes made on your branch.

Comment: Right, I used git-merge and tripped over those conflicts. I am on the `bu-2.24-tic6x-coff` branch, and merge like this:
`wmigda@wmigda-desktop:[bu-2.24-tic6x-coff]:/repo/github/binutils-work2$ git merge bu-2.23.2-tic6x-coff`
with the output like this:
`Auto-merging opcodes/rl78-decode.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in opcodes/rl78-decode.c
Auto-merging opcodes/ppc-opc.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in opcodes/ppc-opc.c
...
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`
And these are conflicts in files I havent touched in my edits.

Comment: @WojciechMigda Well, you have merge srategies: you could say that in case of conflicts, you want to keep the 2.24 version always.

Comment: Hmm, but shouldn't git be smart enough to just do such trivial replacements by itself?

Comment: @WojciechMigda If your changes were done after the other branch changes, yes. But if the changes are done concurrently, no.

Comment: @Ajedi32,@VonC for the moment I have reverted to generating and applying patches - with this (plus some manual patch edit) it worked.

Comment: @WojciechMigda Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.